# A function within a reducer is affecting the wrong state property. I know why but I don't know what to do about it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using a shuffle function in one of my reducers that takes as an argument an array of words from an object within the state. This function then creates a shuffledWords property within the object while keeping the original words array within the object.
The problem I'm getting is that when I put in the original words array into the function the function changes the original words array as well as creating the shuffled words array.

```
//REDUCER CASE
        case 'CREATE_SHUFFLED_WORDS':
            return state.map((dictionary) => {
                if (dictionary.id === action.id) {
                  return {
                    ...dictionary,
                    shuffledWords: shuffle(dictionary.words) 
                  };
                } else {
                  return dictionary;
                };
              });
```

```
Example of what happens:
//Before
{
   words:['cat', 'dog', 'pig']
   shuffledWords: []
}


//AFTER
{
   words:['dog', 'pig', 'cat']
   shuffledWords: ['dog', 'pig', 'cat']
}
```

```
//SHUFFLE FUNCTION
export const shuffle = (a) => {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I thinks the params you passed in your function take the copy of your dictionary. Try to pass it like this : suffle(...dictionary.words)

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi When I tried I got an error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '2' of string 'cat'. I'll post the shuffle function I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your `shuffle(dictionary.words)`. As I can not see the shuffle() method, I am suggesting a solution without modifying the shuffle method,

you can call the shuffle method like this,

```
shuffledWords: shuffle([...dictionary.words])
```

Comment: This solved my problem thank you very much.